# Limiting Number of Signups Per User Pool

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

is there a way to limit the number of users that are allowed to signup in *Cognito* per User Pool? The idea is to create a tier based plan that allows an organization to only be able to create a certain number of users (eg. basic plan - 3 users, pro - 10 users, etc...). I'm thinking of tackling this with the *presignup* trigger but I'm not sure if that's the way to go or if there's a better way to handle this.

Answer (score 1):

From the [Pre Sign-up docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/user-pool-lambda-pre-sign-up.html):

> The pre sign-up Lambda function is triggered just before Amazon
>   Cognito signs up a new user. It allows you to perform custom
>   validation to accept or deny the registration request as part of the
>   sign-up process

So far so good.  But you may have challenges *counting* the number of users in the pool.  The best I found was the ability to [ListUsers](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito-user-identity-pools/latest/APIReference/API_ListUsers.html) and that could get expensive if you've got a large user pool.

In that case I would still use the pre-sign up Lambda but store the count of users somewhere.  Perhaps a DynamoDB table or updating the user pool with a tag that has the number of users.

Comment: Thanks! I'll take these into consideration.